# Measure not yet created SVG text in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a function that will measure how big a text element will be in a SVG element. The code examples I found at Stack Overflow does not work and gives a width of zero. If I delay the measurement I can get the text, but not right away. How is this solved?

```js
var messureSVGtext = function(text, svg, options){
   var text = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'text');
   text.style.fontFamily = options.font;

   text.setAttribute("style",
        "font-family:" + options.font + ";" +
        "font-size:" + options.fontSize + "px;"
   );

   var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);

   text.appendChild(textNode);

   svg.appendChild(text);

   // This does not work
   console.log(text.clientWidth);
      
   //This does
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(text.clientWidth);
   }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Read the comments below the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "computed style" of an element and then check the width & height from that.

Give the element an `id` attribute and after it is appended to the DOM, try this:

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("text_elem");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);

console.log(style.width, style.height);
```

---

### Working example

*SVG*

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    width="640"
    height="480"
    viewBox="0 0 640 480"
    style="display:block">

    <text id="svg_text" x="20" y="50" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:36px; fill:#BADA55">Hello World!</text>

</svg>
```

*JavaScript*

```
function getCompStyle(oid, cbf)
{
    var obj, stl, itv;

    obj = document.getElementById(oid);
    itv = setInterval(function()
    {
        stl = window.getComputedStyle(obj, null);

        if (stl && (stl.width.indexOf('0') != 0))
        {
            clearInterval(itv);
            cbf(stl);
        }
    },0);

}

getCompStyle('svg_text', function(style)
{
    console.log(style.width);
});
```

To use the example, place the SVG in your HTML `<body>` and the JavaScript in a `<script>` tag below the SVG - also in the `<body>`.

Comment: This gives the same result. Width and height is zero when I want to check it but the right size a while after.

Comment: The problem is just that, I don't want to wait an arbitrary amount of time before getting the value. The solution could be asynchronous but then I need the moment it is added to the DOM.

Comment: I'm glad you took time to try to solve this. But a busy wait is just not acceptable in what I'm building (would argue it's not in anything).

Comment: @Lindell :: The answer is updated with a working sample, it works instantaneously (no wait) ... no alteration was required, it worked.

Comment: Make an event trigger when the DOM is ready, then listen on that event. My answer assumed that the JS run only when the required DOM elements are ready. Please comment if I should update the answer with the event listener in place.